# How to save raw HTML content of a webpage to file? Webpage gets content from APIs/scripts

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The webpage I want to download gets much of its content from API or scripts. When I download the webpage on Firefox (Cmd + S) the downloaded file has the same API and script calls, and if I don't authenticate properly or I open the file when I have no internet, that content doesn't load.

Is there a way to download the raw html of a web page exactly as it appears, with all content loaded by scripts? And not download the scripts themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this in Chrome.

First you go to the page, you wish to save.

Then you go to: `File` >> `Save Page As`:

[image: save page 1]

[image: save page 2]

[image: save page 3]

**Please note:** It differs from page to page, how it is coded. And if you can simply open the HTML-file afterwards or not.